# Could not resolve a service of type 'x.y.z'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm getting a 500 error when I try access an object I've injected using `services.AddSingleton<>()` in the `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs`:

Could not resolve a service of type `proj.Auth.IAuthProvider` for the parameter `authProvider` of method `Configure` on type `proj.Startup`.

As far as I can tell from looking at "working" code samples this should be working...

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOptions();
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration);
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthProvider, TranslatorAuthProvider>();
    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IAuthProvider authProvider)
{
    ...

    app.Run(async context =>
    {
        await authProvider.GetToken();
    });

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

TranslatorAuthProvider.cs:

```
namespace proj.Auth
{
    public class TranslatorAuthProvider : IAuthProvider
    {
        public TranslatorAuthProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IOptions<AppSettings> settings)
        {
            ...
        }

        public async Task<OAuthToken> GetToken()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

IAuthProvider.cs:

```
namespace proj.Auth
{
    public interface IAuthProvider
    {
        Task<OAuthToken> GetToken();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's expected. It fails to resolve `IHttpContextAccessor`, because the `IHttpContextAccessor` is not registered by default since recently (see [#190](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/190))

You should register it manually in `ConfigureServices()` like so

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```